# How does work それが and ため in the context of ･･･それが熊のために騙されて･･･?

Tags: meaning

How does **それが**熊の**ため**に騙されて、work here? Especially, それが and ため? I feel like それが is introducing the reason of why the tail of the monkey was supposedly very long; however, I cannot really explain ため and I think that the meaning would not change even if not present. I think this is this definition of ため ([goo辞書](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/139016/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81/) `２ 原因・理由。わけ。「雨の為に延期する」` and that it could simply be replaced by で.

---

The full story for reference:

> “昔の昔の大昔、猿の尻尾は三十三尋あったそうです。**それが熊のために騙されて**、あのような短い尻尾になってしまいました。或時猿は熊のうちへ尋ねて行って、どうすれば沢山の川の魚を、捕ることが出来るだろうかと相談しました。そうすると熊が言うには、今晩のような寒い晩に、どこか深い淵の上の岩に坐って、その尻尾を水の中へ漬けて置いてごらん。きっと色々な雑魚が来てくっつくからと教えてくれました。猿は大喜びで教えてもらった通りにして待っていますと、夜が更けて行くうちに、段々と尻尾が重くなりました。それが氷が張って来たのでしたが、お猿は雑魚が来てくっついたのだと思っていました。もう是くらい捕れたら十分だ。あんまり冷たいから還りましょうと思って、尻尾を引き上げようとしたけれどもなんとしても抜けません。これは大変だと大騒ぎをして、無理に引張ったところが、其尻尾が根元からぷっつりと切れました。猿の顔の真赤なのも、その時あまりに力を籠めて引張った為だと言っている人があります。”
>   -- （日本の昔話、柳田国男、Ｐ１７）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「昔の昔の大昔、猿の尻尾は三十三尋あったそうです。**それ**が熊の**ため**に騙されて、あのような短い尻尾になってしまいました。」

First, 「それが」.

As you have said (or at least implied), this is ***not*** the usual "demonstrative pronoun + subject marker".  「それが」 in this context is used for its idiomatic meaning of "**Here's the thing.**"  This usage of 「それが」 is reserved for the start of an explanation of a negative event or experience.  We also use 「それがね」、「それがな」、「それがですね」 for this purpose.

Next, 「ため」.

In this context, 「ため」 indicates the reason or cause of an event. 「熊のために」 means the same thing as 「熊の**せい**で」、「熊の行為によって」, etc.  This 「ため」 is quite different from the 「ため」 that means "for" as in "doing something for someone".

Hope this helps.